# How to properly retrieve unsigned bigint from MySQL column with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, integer-overflow, bigint

I'm not sure if it's PHP or MySQL that's messing me up.

Say, I have a table with `BIGINT UNSIGNED` column (let's name it `flgs`). I read data from that table with PHP as such:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `$tbl_nm` ORDER BY `$colID` ASC";

$res = mysqli_query($link, $query);
if($res)
{
    while($aRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
        echo("flags=0x".dechex($aRow['flgs'])."<br>");
    }
}
```

if the `flgs` column has value with bit-63 reset, then I get the correct result. But if bit-63 is set, the return value is `0x7fffffffffffffff`. Hmmmm?

For instance, if `flgs` is set to `0x8000000000000000` in the database, my code above prints:

> flags=0x7fffffffffffffff

Why, PHP, why?

Comment: @Shadow:  how is it a duplicate? This is not about displaying a column as a hex. Did you even try to understand it?

Comment: Sorry to point out, but your question, as it is written, is about displaying a column in hex. If that's not what you are after, then you should have made that clear. But added another duplicate on handling unsigned bigints in php.